# Create user identified as admin

Tags: mysql, triggers, sql-insert, create-table, createuser

The syntax is this:

```
CREATE USER 'Adrian' IDENTIFIED BY 'Admin';

GRANT ALL ON `Spital`.* TO 'Adrian';
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, TRIGGER, UPDATE, DELETE ON TABLE `Spital`.* TO 'Adrian';
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, TRIGGER ON TABLE `Spital`.* TO 'Adrian';
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE `Spital`.* TO 'Adrian';
GRANT EXECUTE ON ROUTINE `Spital`.* TO 'Adrian';
```

How can I create the routine?

This is what is showing after that syntax:

```
CREATE USER 'Adrian' IDENTIFIED BY 'Admin'
```

> Error Code: 1396. Operation CREATE USER failed for 'Adrian'@'%'

Comment: Do you have the CREATE USER privilege? Run `SHOW GRANTS` to check your own privileges.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you first deleted a user with DELETE FROM ... and are now trying to recreate it.
You first need to say DROP USER ... then you can recreate again.

for more details you can check:
[https://sebhastian.com/mysql-error-1396/#:~:text=The%20MySQL%20ERROR%201396%20occurs,from%20your%20MySQL%20database%20server](https://sebhastian.com/mysql-error-1396/#:%7E:text=The%20MySQL%20ERROR%201396%20occurs,from%20your%20MySQL%20database%20server).

Comment: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`spital`.* TO 'Adrian'' at line 1

Comment: this annother error that i have

Comment: you need to use single quotes -> 'Adrian'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).